# Why is a Perl UTF-8 string inserted into DB converted to HTML code.

Tags: sql-server, perl, utf-8

When i try to insert an UTF-8 String from a Perl formular into a MS SQL DB it is converted to html code.
 
`INSERT INTO db(column) VALUES('КЛМНОПРСТУФ')`
results in
`&#1050;&#1051;&#1052;&#1053;&#1054;&#1055;&#1056;&#1057;&#1058;&#1059;&#1060;` entry in DB.
Using the SQL Management Studio `INSERT INTO db(column) VALUES(N'КЛМНОПРСТУФ')` directly works fine.
 Datatype of the column is nvarchar().
Who is responsible for this behavior, DBD::ODBC (V1.43), MSSQL 2008R2 or some else?`

Comment: Since I've never experienced anything like this when inserting data into nvarchar columns in MSSQL 2008R2 from .NET, I would guess the problem is on the perl end of things (either the DBD::ODBC module or something else)

Comment: There's a difference between your two SQL INSERT statements - `VALUES('КЛМНОПРСТУФ')` vs `VALUES(N'КЛМНОПРСТУФ')`. Is that a typo or a potentially important clue?

Comment: Actually i used placeholder in the sql statement. This was only to show the UTF-8 value i tried to insert into the DB. But the behavior stays the same even if i use ...VALUES(N'КЛМНОПРСТУФ') within the Perl script.

Answer (score 3):

You provided next to no information since you're focused on blaming the least likely culprit (the database). Why would the database know anything about HTML, much less produce it? Assuming that's actually what's in the database, it's a pretty sure thing that's what you actually put into the database. Check that!

My best guess is that a you got the data from a web browser which HTML-encoded the data as a last resort since the page's encoding didn't include the character it needed to transmit.